# Cutting the column including size

Tags: linux, bash, cut, ls

I want to cut the column which include the size of files . I use `ls -l` to view info about files in current localization . I save info about file in txt file `ls -l > info.txt` , and now I want to cut the column including size . I do `cat info.txt | cut -d'' -f6` but i don't work . What I do wrong ?

This include info.txt :

```
-rwx------ 1 s10891 Domain Users   2188 May  4 14:51 info.txt
-rwx------ 1 s10891 Domain Users   1640 Mar 10 07:43 code.txt
-rwx------ 1 s10891 Domain Users     68 Mar  4 11:59 sorted.txt
drwx------ 1 s10891 Domain Users      0 Jan 11 09:48 PPJ
drwx------ 1 s10891 Domain Users      0 Sep  7  2012 public_html
drwx------ 1 s10891 Domain Users      0 Apr 15 11:16 RBD
drwx------ 1 s10891 Domain Users      0 Jan  7 09:45 RDB
drwx------ 1 s10891 Domain Users      0 Apr 15 12:00 SOP
drwx------ 1 s10891 Domain Users      0 Apr  8 12:53 sop_ex3
-rwx------ 1 s10891 Domain Users    122 Feb 25 11:48 sop_info.txt
drwx------ 1 s10891 Domain Users  0 Jan 14 09:41 WindowsFormsApplicati
drwx------ 1 s10891 Domain Users      0 Jan 14 09:41 WindowsFormsApplicati
drwx------ 1 s10891 Domain Users      0 Jan 14 09:41 WindowsFormsApplicati
```

and I want to get this :

```
2188
1640
68
0
0
0
0
0
0
122
0
0
0
```

Comment: please edit your question to include expected output. Also do you really mean an null -d (delimiter) `''`, try `' '`? Good luck.

Comment: ls output is always risky to be parsed. Seems you are interested in size, why not check the `du` command. It might give you better ideas

Answer (score 21, accepted):

most `cut`s count literal characters, so for `-f 6` to work, your data has to be exactly in the same columns. Not sure if your 3rd to last line is a typo or an exact reproduction of your output, but it illustrates the problem with cut perfectly.

For this case, most people will use an `awk` solution:

```
 ls -l | awk '{print $6}'
```

Will produce the output you have listed

The beauty of awk is that field 6 is determined by the value of awk FS variable (field separator), which defaults to "multiple white space values" (space or tab) (this is not an exact description, but is close enough for your needs).

Comment: Cut will still work just fine. You can make an output like that look nice and neat if you pipe the column command.  "ls -l | column -t" It's very handy for the df and mount commands.

Comment: Sounds good and thanks for sharing! (but ... ) `-ksh: column: not found [No such file or directory]` . good luck to all.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to parse `ls`: `stat -c %s *` will give you a column of sizes. If you want the filename too: `stat -c "%s %n" *`

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
ls -l | sed -E 's/ +/ /g'
```

" +" means any multiple space